# How to: hogan.js and pre-compiling

Tags: hogan.js

I have a question: How can I pre-compile with the hulk? It is a feature of hogan.js.

On many sites I just read you have to pre-compile your templates with hulk but there is no presentation how to do it.

My project structure looks like:

```
myproject
--libs
----lib
------hogan.js
------compiler.js
------template.js
----bin
------hulk
--index.html
--tpl
----Tpl.html
```

As you can see I want to pre-compile Tpl.html in tpl directory.

I am using windows. Nodejs is installed and system environment variable
is set for nodejs.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: hulk ~/path/to/templates/*.hogan -o ~/path/to/output/dir